# Larget format release cable jam

Tags: shutter-release, large-format

Any suggestions for a large format lens (Kodak Ektar 127mm f/4.7) that jams with an external release cable.  It seems to work perfectly with the build in trigger but when I use an external release cable it doesn't trigger or reset correctly.  (It feels as if the release post is binding up within the lens.)

It almost feels like the screw socket for the release cable is bent.

Comment: Did you consider trying another cable release made by another manufacturer (Gepe, Kaiser, Bower, Linhof) if any works better?

Comment: I only had the one shutter release.  When you look at the lens you can see the bracket the cable screws into is slightly bent and the lever the cable pushes is off to the side of the hole.

Answer (score 1):

I screwed in the release cable and torqued on the connection to bend the socket towards the trigger. To be honest I think I broke some of the threads on the release socket... but now if I slightly cross thread the release cable it seems to be in correct alignment as it triggers correctly.  I'm not sure I would call this "fixed" but it seems to have resolved my current issue. (Probably not the best solution but it would probably cost more to have this lens serviced and repaired than I paid for the entire camera. [Busch Model D Pressman.])